# Why can't I install oh-my-zsh to a Mac in China?

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh, open-source

I am in China, my Mac OS is macOS Ventura 13.6.4 I used the Terminal to input:

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

but the output is :

```
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to raw.github.com: 443
```

Who can tell me how to install ohmyzsh?

Comment: Can't you get a cheap return flight to Taiwan (or some another country close by), do all your installations there?

Answer (score 1):

China blocks the installer you’re calling [according to the project Readme.md](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh#basic-installation).

Try:

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://install.ohmyz.sh/)"
```

If that also fails, first thing is to understand if you can even download the install script.

Run this command:

```
curl -L https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh -o /dev/null ; echo $?
```

This will show any errors you have suppressed in your first command and discard the output received from GitHub.com

If you can't get to that server on your network, you may need to try another or use a VPN. If that item is unreachable, perhaps get homebrew.sh to help install this? It has some other help but adds steps if you don't need a package manager and just want this one item.

Here's what success looks like for me with the above test:

```
me@m2 ~ % curl -L https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh -o /dev/null ; echo $?
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 18230  100 18230    0     0  84930      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 84930
0
```

Once the script above works on a network, then you can try again your steps. Pay attention to the last number reported (It's the ***0*** in my case, indicating no error in the `curl`), it's your error code and also any warnings you see that I didn't paste above that drive next steps....

Comment: The o-m-z Github [page](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh) states that it installs from githubusercontent.com, and that China blocks that domain.  It does talk about mirrors.  Homebrew installs from the same domain.

Comment: Well, that deserves an edit. Thanks @MarcWilson